# Graphing each trigonometric function and its inverse

Tags: pgfplots

May I have the code for graphing each trigonometric function and its inverse on the same Cartesian plane?  I have the following code for only graphing the sine function, and I got the following error:  sorry, the supplied plot command is unknown by `pgfplots`.  Please give me a web site for the syntax for the `\begin{axis}` command.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200,no marks,
xticklabels={-2$\pi$,-1.5$\pi$,...$\pi$,2$\pi$},x post scale=1.5]
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As requested: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Answer (score 1):

Just for typing exercise.

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-math,pst-plot}

\def\f{sin(x)}
\def\finv{ASIN(x)}

\psset
{
    xtrigLabels,
    ytrigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=2,
    plotpoints=200,
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-\psPi,-\dimexpr\pstPI2 cm +\pstPI4 cm)(\dimexpr\psPiTwo cm +\pstPI2 cm,\dimexpr\pstPI2 cm +\pstPI4 cm)
    \psaxes[dx=\pstPI2,dy=\pstPI2]{->}(0,0)(-\psPi,-\dimexpr\pstPI2 cm +\pstPI4 cm)(\dimexpr\psPiTwo cm +\pstPI4 cm,\dimexpr\pstPI2 cm +\pstPI4 cm)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{strokeopacity=.5}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{Pi 2 div neg}{TwoPi}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-1}{1}{\finv}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For more general template, please visit [my another answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147793/19356).