# latex, graph y=sin2x, use tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw [<->,thin] (-5,0) - - (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [<->,thin] (0,-3) - - (0,3) node [above] {$y$};


      \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
       \draw[color=red]   **plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})**   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};       
       \end{tikzpicture}
```

how can I draw the sin2x!!!!I already draw the sinx!! please help!!!

Comment: Welcome! `\draw[color=red,smooth] plot (\x,{sin(2+\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};` or `\draw[color=orange,smooth] plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};`? Note that in order to multiply two variables you need to use a `*`.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw [<->,thin] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
 \draw [<->,thin] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [above] {$y$};
 \draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
 \draw[color=red,smooth] plot (\x,{sin(2+\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};       
 \draw[color=orange,smooth] plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};       
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`.

Comment: how do I draw y=sin(x+2)??? \draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,{sin(2+\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};    this is not correct. thanks for the help!!! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Maybe `\draw[color=red,smooth] plot (\x,{sin(deg(2+\x))})   node[right] {$f(x) = \sin (x+2)$};` since Ti*k*Z uses degrees for the arguments of trigonometric functions?

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Great! Would you agree that your question is basically the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147771/194703)?

Comment: I saw that one. Yes the {deg} is same! I did not read carefully,that's my bad

Comment: No worries! So unless you say otherwise this question will then be closed as a duplicate.